# Android View Won't Slide in from Off Screen in Landscape

Tags: android, view, translation, objectanimator, animator

I have a view that I want to slide in from off screen. The following code works perfectly in Portrait mode:

```
// Guarantees it's off screen to start (can't use height because at this point it's 0)
ObjectAnimator mSlideInAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
        myView, "translationY", 
        -5000);
mSlideInAnimator.setDuration(0);
mSlideInAnimator.start();

// Must be done after view is created
myView.post( new Runnable() {    
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // For Animator, 0 is the object's original start position

        ObjectAnimator mSlideInAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                myView, "translationY", 
                -myView.getHeight(), 0);
        mSlideInAnimator.setDuration(DURATION_SLIDE_IN);
        mSlideInAnimator.start();
    }
});
```

(I have it start out way off screen to prevent a brief "blip" as the view is transported to its official "starting" location. No, setting visibility to gone will not work for my purposes.)

However, if I am in landscape mode, the direction of movement is all correct (I tested it with 0 instead of -5000), but while it works for values between 0 and the height of the view, if the initial animation moves it offscreen, the second animation no longer works.

This is only true in landscape mode --- it works fine in portrait.

Why is that so and how do I get around it?